# Okta Spring Security

Tags: okta

Attempting to get a basic Spring Security and Okta setup working.

Have followed the instructions here:

http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/spring_security_saml.html

But experiencing the following IDP error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/spring-security-saml2-sample] threw exception [org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: No IDP was configured, please update included metadata with at least one IDP] with root cause
org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: No IDP was configured, please update included metadata with at least one IDP
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.getDefaultIDP(MetadataManager.java:795)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl.populatePeerEntityId(SAMLContextProviderImpl.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl.getLocalAndPeerEntity(SAMLContextProviderImpl.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.commence(SAMLEntryPoint.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:168)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anyone experienced the same? Any help from Okta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may not have configured Okta as an IDP yet.  Please make sure you follow the instructions here http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/spring_security_saml.html#configuring-okta-to-work-with-spring-security-saml

Once you have set up the SAML app in Okta, you must configure "securityContext.xml" on the Spring side with the SAML metadata in order for your app to recognize Okta as an IDP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about having multiple IDP's to be configured for your app authentication, you can define defaultIDP property as below.

Make sure you setup configure org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider or org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider for your bean defn above.

This will get you to IDP based federation working. To enable SP federation refer to Spring SAML configuration guide on pivotal.io